# Encountering 400 Bad Request Error When Sending Form Information to API through Elementor

Tags: php, api, http

I’m currently working with an API and Elementor, and I’m trying to send form information to the platform API. However, I’m encountering a 400 Bad Request error when making a request to my server. The error message indicates that some parameters are missing from my request. Here’s the error from debug_log:

```
{
    "code": "400",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "msg": "Some parameters are required",
    "schema": [
        {
            "customer_name": "my name",
            "customer_last_name": "my last name",
            "id_type": "CC",
            "customer_id": "113xxxx00",
            .....
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the error from admin-ajax.php :

```
array(4) { ["code"]=> string(3) "400" ["error"]=> string(11) "Bad Request" ["msg"]=> string(28) "Some parameters are required" ["schema"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(37) { ["customer_name"]=> string(7) "my name" ["customer_last_name"]=> string(12) "my last name" ["id_type"]=> string(2) "CC" ["customer_id"]=> string(9) "113xxxx00" ["age"]=> string(2) "30" ["gender"]=> string(1) "M" ["country"]=> string(3) "COL" ["state"]=> string(0) "" ["city"]=> string(0) "" ["zone"]=> string(0) "" ["address"]=> string(0) "" ["opt1"]=> string(0) "" ["opt2"]=> string(0) "" ["opt3"]=> string(0) "" ["opt4"]=> string(0) "" ["opt5"]=> string(0) "" ["opt6"]=> string(0) "" ["opt7"]=> string(0) "" ["opt8"]=> string(0) "" ["opt9"]=> string(0) "" ["opt10"]=> string(0) "" ["opt11"]=> string(0) "" ["opt12"]=> string(0) "" ["tel1"]=> string(11) "9301500xxxx" ["tel2"]=> string(0) "" ["tel3"]=> string(0) "" ["tel4"]=> string(0) "" ["tel5"]=> string(0) "" ["tel6"]=> string(0) "" ["tel7"]=> string(0) "" ["tel8"]=> string(0) "" ["tel9"]=> string(0) "" ["tel10"]=> string(0) "" ["tel_extra"]=> string(0) "" ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["recall_date"]=> string(14) "YYYYmmddHHiiss" ["recall_telephone"]=> string(11) "9301500xxxx" } } }
```

I have already added the parameters as indicated by the schema, but it doesn’t seem to work. I’m still getting the same error.This is my code:

```
 function send_to_external_api( $record, $handler ) {
       
       $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );
    
       if ( 'Testing' !== $form_name ) {
           return;
       }
    
    $raw_fields = $record->get( 'fields' );
       $fields = [];
       foreach ( $raw_fields as $id => $field ) {
           $fields[ $id ] = $field['value'];
       }
    
    
       $body = array(
      'customer_name' => $fields['customer_name'],
        'customer_last_name' => $fields['customer_last_name'],
        'id_type' => $fields['id_type'],
        'customer_id' => $fields['customer_id'],
        'age' => $fields['age'],
        'gender' => $fields['gender'],
        'country' => $fields['country'],
        'state' => '',
        'city' => '',
        'zone' => '',
        'address' => '',
        'opt1' => '',
        'opt2' => '',
        'opt3' => '',
        'opt4' => '',
        'opt5' => '',
        'opt6' => '',
        'opt7' => '',
        'opt8' => '',
        'opt9' => '',
        'opt10' => '',
        'opt11' => '',
        'opt12' => '',
        'tel1' => '',
        'tel2' => '',
        'tel3' => '',
        'tel4' => '',
        'tel5' => '',
        'tel6' => '',
        'tel7' =>'',
        'tel8' => '',
        'tel9' => '',
        'tel10' => '',
        'tel_extra' => '',
        'email' => '',
        'recall_date' => $fields['recall_date'],
        'recall_telephone' => $fields['recall_telephone']
           
       );
    
       $response = wp_remote_post('', [
           'headers'   => [
               'wolkvox-token' => '', 
               'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
           ],
              'body'      => json_encode($body),
 'redirection' => 10,
    'httpversion' => '1.1',
       ]);
        error_log(print_r($body, true));
    
       if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
           $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
       
       } else {
           $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
           $decoded_response = json_decode( $body, true );
           var_dump( $decoded_response );
       }
     
    }
    
    add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/new_record', 'send_to_external_api', 10, 2 );
```

According to Wolkvox, there shouldn't be any issue with leaving those parameters empty.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Diane, I've been trying to provide help but I'm not getting answers to my comments from any of your questions.  You'll likely get a better response if you add to one question rather than continuing to add new questions to the stack.  Error 400 is bad parameters not bad field data. (although last name could be a required field)

On one of your last questions you posted your URL as this:

`https://wv{{wolkvox_server}}.wolkvox.com/api/v2/campaign.php?api=add_record&type_campaign=predictive&campaign_id={{campaign_id}}&campaign_status={{campaign_status}}`

Someone answered that you need to replace the variables with the correct information.  You didn't respond to that question.  Did you change this and set it up correctly? If you didn't that could be your first error.  If you want help we need to get answers to the questions being asked back to you.  It clearly states in the wolkvox documentation: "In the json the parameters are added according to the operation or process to be performed."  Which means if you didn't fix this URL, parameters can't be defined.

More though, it may be that you need to encode the body (the entire body is a parameter):

```
'body'  => json_encode(array()),
```

or you need other parameters besides timeout (which should be set to 0 according to the wolkvox docs) and blocking:

```
'redirection' => 10,
'httpversion' => '1.1',
```

I'm guessing and providing options.  Without seeing the results of what you're sending or testing directly (did you look at postman yet?) this is the best I can think of to assist.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Did you change this and set it up correctly? Yes, I've already added the correct URL API and the correct token. I've also made this correction: 'body' => json_encode(array()). and, the problem still persists. I've updated the code in my question so that you can see how it looks now.
did you look at postman yet? No, but I've already sent data from WordPress to Wolkvox, though not using Elementor. I added the code as per the documentation, hardcoding it in the JSON, and Wolkvox received that. I believe the API works.